# How to pass ambit/scope to a function in php?

Tags: php, oop

Function `myA` of class `A` calls the function `myB` of class `B` which executes an import:

```
class A
{
  function myA()
  {
    // ambit variables of myA and class B here like:
    // $foo = "bar";
    // ...

    $B = new B();
    $B->myB();
  }
}

class B
{
  function myB()
  {
    // ambit variables of myB and class B here like:
    // $hello = "there";
    // ...

    return include("file.php");
  }
}
```

What I want is that when the import is executed, the ambit/scope of class `A` and function `myA` is taken into account for the imported script instead of the ambit/scope of the class `B` and function `myB`, then the PHP code of `file.php` can know about variable `$foo` of the `myA` function.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean include?  Any reason why you wouldn't just pass an argument to myB?

Comment: Yes, I mean include,

Comment: I don't pass arguments because "myB" is intended to abstract the include process of many archives.

Comment: My initial question would be why? What does file.php do that needs or can access the scope of either myA or myB? Without a more concrete example it's going to be hard to help. Control returns to myA after the include if parameters can't be used. Does file.php implement a common interface?

Comment: Currently many classes like class "A" perform the include process directly, as if "myA ()" instead of calling "myB ()" had include ("file.php"), which is fine. But we are abstracting the include process because we are performing other mandatory operations in class "B". Now what is intended is that any class that needs to import something call "myB" of class "B" who will know where to bring the file to import and perform business operations.

Comment: A scope is not called 'scope' for nothing. The only solution I can think of is using arguments for "myB" or turn file.php in a useable class to make it easy for yourself

Comment: Devon's answer below is a decent option. If B can be generalized to the point where it can make all include (and other) decisions, it sounds like you need new functionality in class A or a parent to class A and not a new distinct class B.

Comment: Pass the variable as a parameter in the method call. Stop trying to break encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Basically I've used the function `Closure::bind` static function to brind the class ambit of the caller and the `extract` function to brind any local variable from the scope caller. Here is how:

```
class A
{
  function myA()
  {
    // ambit variables of myA and class B here like:
    $foo = "bar";
    $myLocalVars = ['foo' => $bar];

    $B = new B();
    $B->myB($this, $myLocalVars);
  }
}

class B
{
  function myB($classAmbit, $localVars)
  {
    $closure = function () use ($localVars)
    {
      // With extract any local var from caller's ambit is now accesible here
      extract($localVars);

      return include("file.php");
    }

    // With Closure::bind, the $this from caller is now accesible in the closure,
    // also any of their members, i.e protected, private and public members
    $closureBinded = Closure::bind ($closure, $classAmbit, get_class($classAmbit));

    return $closureBinded();
  }
}
```